# Array stays empty after assignment

Tags: arrays, c, xcode, malloc, sizeof

When executing this C code:

```
double *t = (double*) malloc(10 * sizeof(double));

printf("%lu\n", sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]);

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   t[j] = 5 * powl((j/10), 0.4);            
   printf("t_j: %lf\n", t[j]);           
}
```

My array has only `0` stored and the size of my array is `1`.

I am using Xcode. With thread sanitiser turned on I get an error that `malloc` can't allocate memory in vm-space.

> malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.

Comment: This statement printf("%lu\n", sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]); does not make sense because  t is not an array. It is a pointer.

Comment: Also this expression (j/10) is always equal to 0 due to the integer arithmetic. You should write ( j / 10.0 )

Comment: There is absolutely no way to get the number of elements a pointer points to. You need to take care of this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `t` is declared as a pointer of the type `double *`.

So the expression `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof( double * ) / sizeof( double )` and does not yield the number of elements in the allocated array.

Also in this statement

```
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]);
```

there is a typo. You need to add one more closing parenthesis.

And though the type `size_t` usually is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long` it is more correctly to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%lu` because the C Standard allows in some implementations to define it as an alias for the type `unsigned long long`.

Also in this expression `(j/10)` there is used the integer arithmetic. So it always evaluates to 0. You should write `(j/ 10.0)` to convert operands of the expression to the common type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the pointer, not the pointed to data.

The `sizeof` trick would only work with an array.

Note that `sizeof` returns `size_t`, not an `unsigned long`. The correct format specifier is `%zu`.

There's no way to get the number of elements a pointer is pointing to. You have keep track of the size yourself.

```
size_t size = 10;
```

Another approach would be to define it as an array:

```
double array[10];
```

And now the `sizeof` idiom would work.

```
t[j] = 5 * powl((j/10), 0.4);
```

> This expression is always equal to `0` due to the integer arithmetic.
> You should write ( j / 10.0 ) – Vlad from Moscow

The cast is not required. It only serves to clutter one's code. `malloc(3)` returns `NULL` to indicate failure, leaving it unchecked risks invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: `t` is a pointer. It is not an array. It doesn't have elements.

Comment: You are right. Doesn't solve my Problem tho

Comment: @Max I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is giving you the size of the object. In your case `sizeof(t)` is giving the size of the pointere

To see the size of the array you need to define it as an array

```
double t[10];

printf("%zu\n", sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]);
```